# React Native Stripe Integration: Stuck on IP/Success/

Tags: android, react-native, expo, stripe-payments

I'm currently working on integrating Stripe payments into my React Native application. I've set up the payment flow where users are redirected to a checkout screen in the browser upon clicking a button. After completing the payment on the checkout screen, the user is redirected back to a URL on my server (http://myip:4242/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}). However, instead of being redirected back to the React Native app, I'm stuck on a screen displaying http://myip:4242/success?session_id= in the browser.

Steps Taken:

```
Configured Stripe payment flow with React Native and Express server.
Implemented checkout session creation and redirection to Stripe checkout screen.
Configured intent-filter in the Android manifest to handle the redirect back to the React Native app.
Verified the settings in the Stripe Dashboard to ensure correct redirection URLs.
Checked and adjusted the handleOpenURL function in the React Native app to handle redirection.
```

Expected Outcome:

Upon successful payment, I expect the user to be redirected back to the React Native app with the session ID parameter appended to the URL so that I can handle the success event within the app.

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated!

```
 const express = require("express");
 const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
 const stripe = require("stripe")(
 "sk_test_numbers"
 );
 const dotenv = require("dotenv");
 dotenv.config();
 const app = express();
 app.use(bodyParser.json());

 const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4242;
 app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));

 let paymentDetails = {};

  app.post("/checkout", async (req, res) => {
  try {
  const priceId = "price_1OrLl7HEI2MJxjfpUnFQoLwk"; // Your price ID
  const quantity = req.body.quantity || 1;
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  mode: "payment",
  success_url:
    "http://myip/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",

  cancel_url: "http://myip/cancel",
  line_items: [
    {
      price: priceId,
      quantity: quantity,
    },
  ],
  payment_method_types: ["card"],
});

    console.log("Checkout session created successfully:", session.id); message
   res.json({ url: session.url });
   }      
     catch (error) {
     console.error(error);
     res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to create checkout session" });
 }
 });
    app.get('/event', async (req, res) => {
    try {
     const events = await stripe.events.list({
      limit: 1,
      });

      res.json(events);
    } 
 catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to retrieve events' });
    }
  });
  app.get("/success", async (req, res) => {
 const sessionId = req.query.session_id;
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(sessionId);
  res.send(`Payment successful! Session ID: ${session.id}`);
  });

  const endpointSecret =
   "secret";

   app.post(
  "/webhook",
      express.raw({ type: "application/json" }),
     (request, response) => {
     const sig = request.headers["stripe-signature"];

    let event;

    try {
     event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.body, sig, endpointSecret);
     }   catch (err) {
      response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
      return;
      }
      switch (event.type) {
  case "payment_intent.succeeded":
    const paymentIntentSucceeded = event.data.object;
    console.log(paymentIntentSucceeded);
    paymentDetails = {
      amount: paymentIntentSucceeded.amount,
      currency: paymentIntentSucceeded.currency,
      status: paymentIntentSucceeded.status,
    
    };

  
    response.status(200).send();

    break;

  default:
    console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
     }
   }
   );
    app.get("/payment-details", (req, res) => {
      res.json(paymentDetails);
     });
```

and react native code

```
     React.useEffect(() => {
    const removeLinkingListener = Linking.addEventListener('url', handleOpenURL);
   
    return () => {
       removeLinkingListener.remove();
    };
   }, []);
   const handleOpenURL = (event) => {
    // Example URL: myapp://checkout-success?session_id=cs_test_123
    const { url } = event;
    if (url.startsWith('myip:4242/checkout-success')) {
       // Extract session ID or other relevant data from the URL
       // Then, handle the success in your app
       console.log('Payment was successful');
    } else if (url.startsWith('http://myip:4242/checkout-cancel')) {
       // Handle the cancellation
       console.log('Payment was canceled');
    }
   };
        <Button
     buttonColor="#2C2C2C"
      textColor="#FFFFFF"
       mode="contained"
      style={{ marginTop: 10, width: '100%', height: 50, borderRadius: 10,       justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}
    labelStyle={{ fontSize: 16 }}
    onPress={async () => {
     try {
     const response = await fetch('http://myip/checkout', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     },
      body: JSON.stringify({
      quantity: 1,
      }),
     });

     const { url } = await response.json();
     if (url) {
    Linking.openURL(url);
    }
   } catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
   }
  }}
    >
    PAGAR
     </Button>
```

Android manifest

```
  <intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="myip" android:port="4242" android:pathPrefix="/checkout-success" />
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="myip" android:port="4242" android:pathPrefix="/checkout-cancel" />
```

i tried also :

```
React.useEffect(() => {
const handleDeepLink = async (event) => {
  const { url } = event;
  if (url.startsWith("http://192.myip:4242/checkout-success")) {
    const sessionId = url.split("session_id=")[1]; // Extract session ID from URL
    console.log("Payment was successful");
    const response = await fetch(
      `http://192.myip:4242/checkout-session?sessionId=${sessionId}`
    );
    const session = await response.json();
    console.log("Checkout Session:", session);
    navigator.navigate("PaymentSuccess");
  } else if (url.startsWith("http://192.myip:4242/checkout-cancel")) {
    console.log("Payment was canceled");
    // navigator.navigate('PaymentCanceled');
  }
};

const subscription = Linking.addEventListener("url", handleDeepLink);

return () => {
  subscription.remove();
 };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to configure a custom URL scheme or Universal link in order to return back to your application from a webview. See: [1]

However, I don't believe Checkout Session `success_url` supports passing in a custom App URL.

The workaround I can think of is;

1. Create a universal link that lets you redirect your users back to your app
2. Set the Universal link as `success_url` when you create checkout session
3. Configure your react native app to handle the universal link

[1] https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking

Comment: i tried do it but still stuck on the browser and can't to be redirected to the app.